# Angular4 svg rect pass value dynamically

Tags: angular, svg, rect

I am building a "BarsChartComponent" and I am using svg rect to display bars. What I am trying to do is to pass width value dynamically.. Code bellow does not display any result:

**Component object to display:**

```
items:any=[{Country:"Canada", Value:"1000"}, 
               {Country:"USA", Value:"800"},
               {Country:"Costa Rica", Value:"400"},
               {Country:"Brazil", Value:"500"}];
```

**Component template:**

```
  <svg class="chart" width="420" height="150" aria-labelledby="title" role="img">
    <ng-template *ngFor="let item of items">
        <rect [attr.width]="item.Value" height="19" y="20"></rect>
    </ng-template>
    </svg>
```

I guess it is a syntax error..
Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-container` instead of the `ng-template`

```
<svg class="chart" width="420" height="150" aria-labelledby="title" role="img"> 
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
    <rect [attr.width]="item.Value" height="19" y="20"></rect> 
  </ng-container>
</svg>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-itqrki?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)