# TypeScript: render params

Tags: html, angular, typescript

field_array = [["S",".","."],[".","#","."],[".",".","T"]];

```
<ng-template ngFor let-row [ngForOf]="field_array" let-x="index">
  <ng-template ngFor let-value [ngForOf]="row" let-y="index">
    {{x*10}}<br>
    {{y*10}}<br>
    <rect fill="white" stroke="#231F20" stroke-width="0.5" x="{{123}}" y="{{y}}" width="10" height="10" opacity="1"></rect> 
  </ng-template>
</ng-template>
```

What I Expect:

```
0<br> 
0<br>
<rect fill="white" stroke="#231F20" x="123" y = "0" stroke-width="0.5" width="10" height="10" opacity="1"></rect> 
0<br> 
10<br>
<rect fill="white" stroke="#231F20" x="123" y = "10" stroke-width="0.5" width="10" height="10" opacity="1"></rect>
....
```

What I Had:

```
0<br> 
0<br>
<rect fill="white" stroke="#231F20" stroke-width="0.5" width="10" height="10" opacity="1"></rect> 
0<br> 
10<br>
<rect fill="white" stroke="#231F20" stroke-width="0.5" width="10" height="10" opacity="1"></rect>
....
```

Why X and Y params aren't rendered in  tag ?

Comment: Please consider revising the code sample you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. -1, don't take it the wrong way. A down vote is how we indicate a content problem around here; improve your formatting and code sample and I (or someone will) gladly revert it. Good luck with your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. 

Change ng-template to ng-conatiner. Source:
[Angular4 svg rect pass value dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47927714/angular4-svg-rect-pass-value-dynamically)
2)
Change x={{x}}, y={{y*10}} to [attr.x]="x", [attr.y]="y*10". Source:
https://metanit.com/web/angular2/2.5.php